# How to sort an mysql Result?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

## Table :

```
 id        title

1.         php is a good language.
2.         Java is a good language
3.         All language are good
4.         Php,Java both good language
5.         Php is good but Java is not
```

## Question

### string: $#

```
$string = "php Java language"
```

### Result Order

```
php ,Java both  good language
-------------------------
php is good Java is not

-------------------------
php is good language 
---------------------------
Java is good language
------------------------
all language are good
```

I have no idea how to achive the order list by how many words are matched in string.

It will be great if you explain the query.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your string to JSON array then

```sql
SELECT test.id, test.tittle
FROM test
LEFT JOIN JSON_TABLE(@criteria, 
                     "$[*]" COLUMNS (word VARCHAR(255) PATH "$")) jsontable ON LOCATE (jsontable.word, test.tittle)
GROUP BY test.id, test.tittle
ORDER BY SUM(jsontable.word IS NOT NULL) DESC
```

`@criteria` is a placeholder for JSON array mentioned above.

Of course, you may provide your criteria as space-separated string and convert it to JSON in the query using string functions.

---

The version without JSON usage:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (SELECT test.id, 
               test.tittle, 
               0 amount, 
               TRIM(TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(@criteria, ' ', 1) FROM @criteria)) criteria, 
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(@criteria, ' ', 1) token
        FROM test
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, 
               tittle,
               amount + (LOCATE(token, tittle) > 0),
               TRIM(TRIM(LEADING token FROM criteria)),
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(criteria, ' ', 1)
        FROM cte
        WHERE TRIM(criteria) != '' )
SELECT id, tittle
FROM cte
GROUP BY id, tittle
ORDER BY MAX(amount) DESC;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ab611ed7429e23be2abfcb8b0186e6d

Comment: Can you do it without json

Comment: @MixUp I can. The solution depends on: precise MySQL version; max. amount of tokens per criteria string.

Comment: the latest MySQL version . Can you explain line by line query.

Comment: And I want a simple query without json. Where I can implement other conditions like if the two row have same no. of words then sort by id etc.

Comment: @MixUp *latest MySQL version* If so then *do it without json* means "provide the criteria as space-separated, as-is", is it? If not then recursive CTE needed - it is useful for you?

Comment: @MixUp Updated.

Comment: Ok man thanks. But I am not understanding what part of SQL query doing what. I will be very great full if you explain the above 2 query.. Please . Explain I want to understand this

Comment: @MixUp For the first query you must study and understand [JSON_TABLE function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html). The rest of the query is trivial. For the second query - read about [Recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive), then see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9da6e45146d0230602fec5084c08e911) - you can see how each row is altered during recurse process.